# Extracting the title attribute with Regex

Tags: regex, macrabbit-espresso

Search

```
<img src="images/foo.jpg" alt="" title="caption here" class="figure" />
```

replace with

```
<img src="images/foo.jpg" alt="" title="caption here" class="figure" /><figcaption>caption here</figcaption>
```

or just (my second choice, good enough)

```
<figcaption>caption here</figcaption>
```

How do I search and replace with regex? I am using TextMate and Espresso. I am not searching in a HTML file, this HTML is small part of my Drupal post. I learnt I should be using a HTML parser. I believe this case is simpler.

Comment: See the following question about parsing HTML with regex:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

In short, parsing HTML with regex isn't the right tool for the job   :)

Comment: Yes, I agree. But my use case is unique, I only copy the img tags and insert to textmate/espress to process. Then copy back to my drupal. Thank you for your direction. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching with:

`(<img[^>]+?title=['"])([^'"]*?)(['"][^>]+?>)`

and replace with:

`$1$2$3<figcaption>$2</figcaption>`